# GLFW simple event handler

Tags: c++, event-handling, glfw

I wrote a simple concept of an event system in cpp.
It is uses a namespace and a global state, but normally a global state with namespaces is bad practice.

Is there a better way to do simple event handling with multiple callback functions?

header:

```
#ifndef EVENTS_EVENTMANAGER_H
#define EVENTS_EVENTMANAGER_H
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

namespace eventmanager
{   

    //resize event
    static std::vector<std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int)>> resizeEventCallbacks;
    void resizeEvent(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int hight);
    void subscribeResize(std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int)> callback);
}

#endif //EVENTS_EVENTMANAGER_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "events/eventmanager.h"

void eventmanager::resizeEvent(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int hight)
{
    for (auto &callback: eventmanager::resizeEventCallbacks)
    {
        callback(window, width, hight);
    }
}

void eventmanager::subscribeResize(std::function<void(GLFWwindow *, int, int)> callback)
{
    eventmanager::resizeEventCallbacks.push_back(callback);
}
```

usage:

```
eventmanager::subscribeResize([&](GLFWwindow *window, int width, int hight) {
            ...

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one major issue:

```
static std::vector<std::function<void(GLFWwindow*, int, int)>> resizeEventCallbacks;
```

You should never put a `static` variable declaration like that in a header. That will cause every file that includes the header to have a local copy of that variable. What you probably want is to put that declaration in the .cpp file so that it is local to that file only. The `resizeEventCallbacks` is an implementation detail that should be known only to `eventmanager.cpp` functions.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that, you are totally right. Do you think the concept with the namespace is ok?

Comment: I think it's fine. If you're going to end up dispatching a lot of different types of events, then it might make sense to have a class or set of classes to do it and keep it organized. But for the small number you've implemented so far, I think it's fine.